# How to periodically 'touch' temporary files on remote server so the files don't get deleted

Tags: emacs, sas, remote-access, remote-server

I log on to the remote server using SAS/Emacs. On the server, there is this space where I can save files for about a week. Unless I refresh or 'touch' those files again, they will get deleted after a week. Is there a macro or a code that I can execute whenever I open SAS/EMACS so that these files stay updated?

So far, I have used SSH to go on to the server and type 'touch /*' to keep it 'touched', but I am hoping there is a better/more efficient way to keep those files touched.

Comment: Why not just use SAS code to run the touch command?

Comment: Do you have XCMD enabled on your SAS installation? If so you can write a small program and have it run as part of your autoexec every time you boot up SAS.

Comment: @Tom, I apologize for my ignorance, but what would be the SAS code to run the touch command?

Comment: @Reeza, I am sorry I really don't know much about all these things so I have no idea what XCMD is. But I do have an autoexe that has all the macros I've written. I am sure that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Do you really want to *depend* upon using Emacs within the intervening week?!  Or are you running an Emacs server long-term on that remote host (and hence it's in a good position to do such things)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using EMacs Speaks Statistics to connect to SAS, then you have a couple of different options.

One is to modify `ess-sas-submit-command` to point to a script that *first* does your "touch" command and *then* starts SAS.

Another is to create an autoexec for SAS to do that for you, assuming you have rights to do so; you can add that to [various locations in Unix](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/hostunx/n01r164ulo7fzwn1ahce64dmxacq.htm) or to the command line itself (depending on how you're launching SAS).

Even if you're not using ESS, the Autoexec method may work for you.

Note that, of course, your system administrator may not appreciate doing this, so do make sure this is permissible (unless that sysadmin is you!).

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. Now, for your first recommendation, currently, I have ess-sas.el file with a following code '(setq-default ess-sas-submit-command
"C:/Progra~1/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sas.exe")'. Would you have any idea how I could add 'touch' line?

Comment: The (new) program you point that variable at has to do both things -- touch the file, and run the command that you're *currently* running.